# How do i set up a grails environment variable?

Tags: file, grails

I have a folder in my d drive.files in this drive i am using in my controller.so in controller i am specifying tht folder name for to each file recurse.But after development files may be saved in any other drive.so I want have environment variable for it.how to do that

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like a configuration parameter would be better than an environment variable. `Config.groovy` is environment aware, so you can specify different values for development, production, etc.

```
environments {
    production {
        fileLocation = "D:/"
    }
    development {
        fileLocation "/somewhere/else"
    }
    test {
        fileLocation "/production/somewhere"
    }    
}
```

You can read the value of this parameter with:

```
def fileLocation = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config?.fileLocation
```

in grails 1.4 `ConfigurationHolder` is deprecated, so you should read config parameters using this instead:

```
def fileLocation = grailsApplication.config.fileLocation
```

Comment: Note that you need to use _grailsApplication.config.fileLocation_ in Grails 1.4, as ConfigurationHolder is removed. Add _def grailsApplication_ to your controller/service etc first.

Comment: @rlovtang - has it been removed or just deprecated? If it's really been removed, then feel free to update this post with a 1.4-compliant example

Comment: I thought it was removed, but it looks like it's deprecated. http://grails.org/1.4.0.M1+Release+Notes

Comment: Added example of using grailsApplication to your post :)